# Interview Q: How to find the most popular number in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, binary-search, sorting

A number is popular if it appears more than or equal to N/4 times (N is the length of array) He wanted me to make use of the sorted property of the array and come up with a better solution than O(n) time complexity.

Comment: How did you attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: I first gave a hashmap solution which required counting occurrences of numbers and returning the one with count >= N/4. Then I was kind of stuck making it better. I knew that the popular number (if it exists) has to be one in positions - 0, n/4 , n/2 , 3n/4 ,n but was not able to come up with a code to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with similar approach as binary search.

At first I would find values of 8 numbers which would be on 0/8, 1/8, 2/8 ... 8/8 of array. The same numbers you find first when you binary search for something.

As the same number must be in n/4 of array size or higher, it must reach at least two of that boundaries in row. Like number at 2/8 and 3/8 is same.

Therefore this identification of number and partially position is done in constant time.

Then you just continue to find where it start and where it ends, which is typical binary search.

Complexity : `O(log n)`